# In Dragonlance, what color is goblin blood?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, dragonlance

In the Dragonlance setting of D&D, what color is goblin blood?

Comment: While this is a perfectly fine question, why do you ask?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Black

At least, in the books it is black.

*Dragons of Autumn Twilight*, Chapter 1, a few paragraphs before the end:

> Flint wiped black goblin blood from his axe blade.

Additional support can be found elsewhere, such as Tales II Vol. I The Reign of Istar, 'The Silken Threads', which mentions black goblin blood several times:

> Her fine silk blouse was splattered with blood, and the
> silver moon's light showed me that it wasn't black goblin blood. It was as red as
> rose petals, and it was hers.

> He pried her fingers from the sword she still held, fingers gummed
> black with goblin blood.

> Akar whistled. A horse as black as goblin's blood - which was, indeed, the
> steed's name - cantered into the clearing, drawing behind it a small wooden cart.